# Related to Web.config in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

If we delete an old Web.Config file and add a new web.config containing a new connection string.
Then the application will use this new web.config by default or do we need to make some changes at some place so that application use this new web.config.

Please advise.
How to make this work.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? This is something you could easily test yourself, right?

Answer (score 1):

The web.config file is loaded dynamically, any updates to it will reflect immediately by causing the application pool to reset.

I would suggest replacing it, rather than deleting it and creating a new one, so that you don't experience any downtime.